# Make A laravel installation file (install.php)

Tags: php, laravel

when if finished a native php script i'd make a (install.php) file to help the user to install the script and fill the database and create admin user with one step...

How can i do that with **laravel**? how can i extract/get the final project and make install file (install.php) after finishing it on my apache server to send it with the install file which will create a user and migrate the database... to the final user..

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need install.php. You can upload your project in **GitHub** or **Bitbucket**, and others will use it by copying that project to their server. That you can have something like `install.php`, which will run `composer update`, `php artisan migrate`, php artisan db:seed` and other commands. Or you can create Custom Command, that will do this things automatically, and ask user to run that command after copying repository.